# javascript regular expression replacement doesnt work?

Tags: javascript, regex

why this regular expression replacement doesnt work?

```
var url = 'http://myweb.com/page/1/id/2'; 

newUrl = url.replace('/page\/[0-9]+/', 'page/2'); //it must become http://myweb.com/page/2/id/2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do **two things**:

1. change `str.replace` to `url.replace`
2. remove the `'` around the regex

   ```
   var url = 'http://myweb.com/page/1/id/2'; 

   newUrl = url.replace(/page\/[0-9]+/, 'page/2');
   ```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/fhqXn/

Answer (score 3):

Use `url` rather than `str`, if you want to replace something in the String stored in the `url` variable.

Answer (score 1):

You have a naming misspell. 
Rename your `url` var to `str` or change the `str.replace` to `url.replace`:

```
newUrl = url.replace('/page\/[0-9]+/', 'page/2');
```